# The meaning of on the way

Tags: meaning

"Anything of interest?"
"No." He tossed a magazine on her desk and said,"This one is on the way. Could be fun."
The expression "on the way" baffles me. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're going to need a little more context here. Maybe he's looking at travel magazines and he's found something on the way to their destination?

Answer (score 3):

This is dialog from John Grisham's novel *The Appeal*, about a Justice on the Mississippi Supreme Court.  She's the one who says, "Anything of interest?"  She's talking to her chief clerk, who has just said that he's been reading briefs (i.e., arguments on cases before the court).  He says, "No," nothing of interest in the briefs, but he indicates that there is something of interest in the magazine he shows her.  It's about a lower court case in which large damages were awarded to the plaintiff.  The losing defendant is sure to appeal, and the appeal will eventually get to the state Supreme Court.  So the clerk says "This one is on the way," meaning that the case is making its metaphoric journey from trial court verdict to Supreme Court appeal.

Comment: With your explanation, the context has cleared. Thank you very much.